# Read Textfile to jTable

Tags: java, exception, jtable, bufferedreader, awt-eventqueue

I'm tryin' to import some data from a textfile to my JTable..
I wrote some code to do this:

```
JMenuItem Open = new JMenuItem("Open gegevens");
    Open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            readTXT();


        }
    });

    mnNewMenu.add(Open);

public void readTXT(){



            try{       
                 String readLine = null;
                File file = new File("Resultaten.txt");
                FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

                while((readLine = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] splitData = readLine.split("; ");
                    System.out.println(splitData.length);
                    String match= splitData[0];
                    String set= splitData[1];
                    String spelertje1= splitData[2];
                    String gamesspeler1= splitData[3];
                    String streep= splitData[4];
                    String gamesspeler2= splitData[5];
                    String spelertje2= splitData[6];
                    String setwinnaartje= splitData[7];
                    String matchwinnaartje= splitData[8];

                   model.addRow(new Object[] { match,set,  spelertje1, gamesspeler1,
                            streep, gamesspeler2, spelertje2, setwinnaartje, matchwinnaartje });
                    System.out.println("okidokii");

                }



                reader.close();
             }
            catch(IOException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        e.printStackTrace();

            }


    }
```

In my opinion this should work but yet i got this :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at TennisKlassement.readTXT(TennisKlassement.java:888)
    at TennisKlassement$14.actionPerformed(TennisKlassement.java:807)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:389)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:137)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

In fact i do understand the problem.. The String splitdata has only one string to hold. yet i intialised it whit the split method..

my txtfiles looks like this :

[image]

This is the code i used to write my jtable to txtfile:

```
public void writeTXT(){
          try {


            File file = new File("Resultaten.txt");

              PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(file );
              System.out.println(os);
              os.println("");




              for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {


                  for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                      //os.print(table.getColumnName(col));
                      os.print(";");
                      os.print(table.getValueAt(row, col) + "\t")

                      System.out.println("ok");

                  }

                  os.println("");
              }
              os.close();
              System.out.println("Done!");
          } catch (IOException e1) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e1.printStackTrace();

      }


        }
```

For your knowledge, nothing happens with the jtable when using this method....

Thanks for your kind response

Comment: Please add the code including `TennisKlassement.readTXT`

Comment: Add `System.out.println(splitData.length)` in the first while loop and report the result please.

Comment: I tried that earlier, Result was 1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The String splitdata has only one string to hold. yet i intialised it whit the split method..

So why did you paste all the code related to the table? Your problem is with the splitting of the text into tokens.

Based on your code it looks like you are writing out a `semi-colon and a tab character`, but it looks like the split is using a `semi-colon and a space character`, so you don't get the tokens your expect.

You can write a simple [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) to test this:

public class Main

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String text = ";\tone;\ttwo;\tthree;\tfour";

        for (String word: text.split("; "))
//      for (String word: text.split(";\t"))
            System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

When you post a question only post the relevant information to understand the problem.

Comment: Well that helped a lot in fact! Now there is no thread anymore and the readLine is divided over the strings but yet nothing appears in my jTable.. Seems really really strange to me

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception and your code seems the length of the splitData is less than 9.

Edit: (As the OP accepts the first part)

Make sure that your file is delimited with ";" and has the required length.

Comment: It seems to be correct..I added the code i used to write my Jtable to txt file

Comment: The easier way is to just check the txt file by eyes.

Comment: Yeah i did that to but my program used to write the jtable to a txt file so it can recover it when opening the program again..  Like an easy way for a databank

Comment: @VanpeltJ> I have the experience of such question chains, indeed I've answered your question and pointed where is the problem. Please ask a new question and completely explain the problems of Writing to a file.